# Bitnami Docker Mariadb no longuer starts [Exec Format error]

Tags: mariadb, bitnami

I have been running for a while an instance of a Bitnami docker image for mariadb. It has been working perfectly for some time but suddently, a couple of days back, it started to fail. Initially the only thing I could see is the docker container restarting every so often without the database being avaiable at any time.

In order to debug the problem, I modified the docker-compose file to override the entrypoint of the maridadb image to something that wold keep the container running so that I could log into it and debug. Doing so I was able to start the mariadb container and then open a session into it.

Once inside the container, I tried executing the **run.sh** and **setup.sh** scripts located in /opt/bitnami/scripts/mariadb/,but both of them failed when trying to run mysqld.

The command executed by the scripts in order to start mariadb:

```
/opt/bitnami/mariadb/sbin/mysqld --defaults-file=/opt/bitnami/mariadb/conf/my.cnf --basedir=/opt/bitnami/mariadb --datadir=/bitnami/mariadb/data --socket=/opt/bitnami/mariadb/tmp/mysql.sock --bind-address=127.0.0.1 --user=mysql --skip-slave-start
```

And the error I get when tring to execute the above command is:

```
bash: /opt/bitnami/mariadb/sbin/mysqld: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

I have tried deleting the image and puling it again and still the problem persists. What could it be that is not allowing mysqld to run ??

The docker-compose file I use to start the containers is shown bellow. The commented "entrypoint" line is what I used to start thecontainer for debuging.

```
version: '2'
services:
  mariadb:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/mariadb:10.6
    user: root
    #entrypoint: tail -f /dev/null
    environment:
      # ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD is recommended only for development.
      - MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxxxx
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=no
      - MARIADB_USER=finquescrm
      - MARIADB_DATABASE=xxxxxxxx
      - MARIADB_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxx
    volumes:
      - 'mariadb_data:/bitnami/mariadb'
      - ./sharedfolder:/sharedfolder
    restart: always
  suitecrm:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/suitecrm:7.12.5-debian-10-r79
    user: root
    ports:
      - '80:8080'
      - '443:8443'
    environment:
      - SUITECRM_DATABASE_HOST=mariadb
      - SUITECRM_DATABASE_PORT_NUMBER=3306
      - SUITECRM_DATABASE_USER=xxxxxxxx
      - SUITECRM_DATABASE_NAME=xxxxxxxx
      - SUITECRM_DATABASE_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxxxx
      # ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD is recommended only for development.
      - MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=no
    volumes:
      - 'suitecrm_data:/bitnami/suitecrm'
      - ./sharedfolder:/sharedfolder
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    restart: always
volumes:
  mariadb_data:
    driver: local
  suitecrm_data:
    driver: local
```

Addendum:
This is what I get from executing the docker compose:
[image]

After that I just keep getting timeout errors and restarts:
[image]

NOTE: Added 9-jan-2023
I have tried starting the cuitecrm and mariadb instances in another computer running docker. I first did a clear install with the docker compose file and the database started without any issues.
After that I transfered the persisted data from the volumes in the computer that is failing to the new computer. I transfered both the suitecrm files and the mariadb files ... After doing so, the problem reproduces.. the problem seems to be then in the persisted data .... How can I try to have mariadb recover the database?

Comment: Can you share the mariadb service specification from your docker-compose? Are you mounting any volumes into that container from your host? `Exec format error` usually means the binary was compiled for a different operating system, which doesn't really make sense here.

Comment: I agree .. it does not make much sense to get an Exec format error when it has been running for some time already in the host. I have extended my question by adding the compose.yml file

Comment: Unfortunately (for solving this) I'm able to bring up your mariadb container with that docker compose just fine, and also able to execute the command with your same entrypoint override. Still, I have a hunch that the exec format error is a red herring and not the root cause. Are you able to get any logs off of the failing containers? Try bringing up just the mariadb service on its own to minimize noise.

Comment: Nothin helpfull seems to appear in the container logs. It all seems to be fine untill I get a message that mariadb is being started in the background and stays there untill it errors out.

Comment: Do you believe the mariadb persisted data (the database data) could be causing this error, and if so ... how could I recover the persisted data?

Comment: I'd believe the error that a different architecture of OS image is here. Run `docker  inspect docker.io/bitnami/mariadb:10.6`. Does the 'Architecture' watch what hardware you are running this image on?

Comment: If you see `Starting mariadb in background` then the container _is_ running but hitting a later error. https://imgur.com/a/LQotjuo is the full logs that I see when bringing up the container. If your logs cut off partway through, it might point out at what step it's failing.

Comment: @danblack I would agree that the error could be caused by a different OS arquitecture, but that same image has been working for quite some time in that same computer. How could that have changed and stopped working?

Comment: You haven't used a -rXX version or a sha hash so its a little dependent on [bitnami release](http://soaphub.org/imagehub/?q=mariadb&n=bitnami&p=1), which appears to be amd64 only. If you are running on a different non-amd64 arch, maybe the qemu/binfmt-misc configuration on the local machine has been stopped and previously it was emulating the amd64 image. Of course the [docker official mariadb](http://soaphub.org/imagehub/?q=mariadb&n=library&p=1) is multi arch, however how your change is still odd. Do you have logs of previous sha versions to see if the image changed?

Comment: I do not have logs from previous situation when it workes. Currently I jut get the following untill it times out (see screen capture added to the description)

Comment: @danblack this is what I get by inspecting the mariadb image:    
                "OS_ARCH=amd64",
                "OS_FLAVOUR=debian-11",
                "OS_NAME=linux",
                "APP_VERSION=10.6.11",
                "BITNAMI_APP_NAME=mariadb"
yet the OS executes correctly but the database does not....

Comment: @danblack I checked my PC architecture where docker is running and it is also AMD64
                echo %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%
                AMD64

Comment: @danblack It is strange .. although in the previous comments everything seems to point that the architecture of the pc and of the image is AMD64, when I open a session into the mariadb container and execute "uname -m" I get x86_64

Comment: Please see additional information added. Please I am getting desperate and I need to recover the application and its data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it has been a while, and fogot about this question which I finally solved.
Not really sure what was going on but the issue got solved by deleting both the container and the related image and executing the docker compose again to recreate them.

After that it just worked again.

Comment: how did you do that?